# How to make form children inline

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Form elements by default are block elements, it seems.

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49t4xwcs/)

When I use input text-box & button within form element, button is moved to next line:
[image]

```
<form action="/" method="post"><input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" type="text" value="">        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Sign up!</button>
  </span></form>
```

When I remove form tag these input & button elements are displayed inline, correctly. What could be wrong?

I tried `display:inline` css but it did not help.
[image]

Comment: Can you please stop randomly inserting > marks into your questions? You should only use them for quoting text that is not your own, but if you cannot distinguish a quotation from your own writing, please just do not make use of that formatting at all.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML from that code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using "input-group" around your form control and button?
http://jsfiddle.net/49t4xwcs/3/

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Sign up!</button>                                    
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have removed form element wrapper, that was base of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 
Style="float:left"
To the search and to the button